# RubyMine: How to select text inside quotes

Tags: rubymine

I use the rubyMine editor but I don't know how a hotkey to select the content inside quotes, for example:

`ng-click="select all this content inside here"`

Double click just selects the whole line.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Edit | Extend Selection action. The hotkey for it is Ctrl-W in the default Windows/Linux keymap and Alt-Up in the Mac OS X 10.5+ keymap.